# Unit test cases for Java Controller based Webscripts in Alfresco

Tags: unit-testing, junit, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I plan to unit test the webscripts that had Java as controllers. I have found two approaches.

1) Go along the lines of bootstrap code `HelloWorldWebScriptControllerTest.java`

2) Follow `https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-remote-api`. Here, the test classes extend `org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.BaseWebScriptTest`.

For the second approach, I tried adding the following dependency, but cannot find this BaseWebScriptTest.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.alfresco/alfresco-remote-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
    <artifactId>alfresco-remote-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.b-EA</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried adding `<classifier>tests</classifier>` to the above dependency as well. But, cannot find this class.

How can this issue be resolved? Also, which approach is suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Use the bootstrap code example. It is simple and it works. I see no reason to make it any more complicated.

However, if you look at the Alfresco source, you'll see that class under
./projects/repository/source/test-java/org/alfresco/repo/web/scripts/BaseWebScriptTest.java